# What does this statement with List and ArrayList mean?

Tags: java

I am reading the Drools Planner examples and I came across code like this a lot:

```
List<Column> columnList = new ArrayList<Column>(n);
```

As far as I get it, it is supposed to initialize a list of length n which stores the `Column` datatype.

---

But what is the deal with having **different collection datatypes** on either side of the expression?

If `ArrayList<Column>` type-matches with  `List<Column>`, what makes it different from doing:

```
List<Column> columnList = new List<Column>(n);
```

Comment: List is an interface, you can't instantiate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List` is an interface. You can't create instances of interfaces.

`ArrayList` is a class which implements List, you can create one.

An interface just defines behavior.  A class that implements and interface implements that behavior.

You will note that if you [look at the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), many different classes implement the `List` interface.  That's because they all provide implementations for the methods that `List` defines.  Moreover, those implementations are likely mostly different, because and `ArrayList` works differently than, say, a `LinkedList`.

It is preferable to use the form

`List list = new ListType()`

because you can change the list implementation later, if you want to, without affecting your code.  The reason for this is if you do

`ListType list = new ListType()`

the type of list is `ListType`, which only an instance of `ListType` and subclasses have.

If you do the preferred assignment shown above, then you can assign **anything** that implements `List` to `list`.

Answer (score 6):

`List` is an interface. `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List`.

You can't do `new List<Column>(n)` because `List` simply defines methods that must be implemented.

The idea behind having `List = (some implementation)` is you can have implementation-agnostic code that behaves according to the contract of an interface. (ie: You could replace ArrayList with LinkedList and it'll just work, though it'll be implemented entirely differently and will obviously have different performance characteristics).

Answer (score 6):

List is an interface and cannot be instantiated, so `new List` will trigger a compile-time error. You can do `ArrayList<Column> columnList = new ArrayList<Column>(n);`, but this way you can't easily switch between different `List` implementations(`ArrayList` is one of them).

Comment: When and why we may need to switch between different `List` implementations?

Answer (score 1):

List is actually an interface and therefore can not be instantiated. So in order to use list, you must create an object of its implementation, for example: ArrayList. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html for more information

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote to the other answers, it's worth noting that `List` is the compile-time type of `columnList` and `ArrayList` is the runtime type.