# How do I declare a 2D String arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to do something like this `ArrayList<String<String>> mylist`

How can I create it?

How can I add to the external and internal list

and how can I convert the internal list to a simple array list?

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can go with

```
List<List<String>> ls2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
x.add("Hello");
x.add("world!");
ls2d.add(x);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls2d.toArray()));
```

Comment: how do we print the List `ls2d` as index vise. What I mean is printing the first element of the `ls2d` list then 2 element and so on

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya use a loop like `for` or `while`. For example: `for(List<String> inner : ls2d) { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ls2d.toArray())); }`.

Comment: How do you access an element in the rows?

Comment: Why did you decide to have the outer List as ArrayList and let the inner List be a List?

Comment: @sbhatla `List` is an interface, so objects have to be initialized using a concrete class that implements this interface like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: Why is the inner class still initialized as a "List" and not "ArrayList"?

Answer (score 12):

The first array list isn't an array list of String, it's an ArrayList of ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

Comment: Crap, should've posted an answer instead of a comment :p

Comment: How do I add to the second list?

Comment: user521190, the first array list isn't an array list of String, it's an arraylist of arraylist.

Comment: I still don't understand why people declare `ArrayList` instead of `List`, remember to develop oriented to interfaces. Also, check [TypeList vs type ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2279030/1065197)

Comment: That's a separate question. Here... let me google it for you... http://bit.ly/LEhHht

Comment: I mean if you want to teach programming in Java, you should do it in the right way, not just the thing that can run :).

Comment: you asked a question, and I answered it! :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - Luiggi is right, it is helpful to explain *why* something works in StackOverflow answers. I'll add your comment to your answer in case one of the mods deletes them :)  Please see [point #10 on this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/155826) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<String>> array = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
...
array.add(new ArrayList<String>())
array.get(0).add("qqq");
```

array.get(0) - is a internal list

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<String>> super2dArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()
```

This is an arraylist of arraylists holding strings.

Also `ArrayList<String<String>> mylist` makes no sense, because String is not a collection/list, but I think you understood that. Future readers might not though.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896608/645270) to see why I chose to have `List` on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve what you desire. I am providing code snippet for both:

**1.`List<List<String>> lol = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = in.nextInt();

//Declare your two dimensional ArrayList of Strings. 
List< List<String>> lol = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

//Instantiate and Populate
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    int internalListSize = in.nextInt(); //the size of each internal list
    lol.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    for (int j=0;j<internalListSize;j++){
        String whateverYouWanttoPut = in.nextLine();
        lol.get(i).add(whateverYouWanttoPut);
    }
}

//Access Elements 
try {
    System.out.println(lol.get(0).get(4));
    System.out.println(lol.get(1).get(2));
    System.out.println(lol.get(3).get(2));
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("ERROR!");
}
```

**2. `ArrayList[] set = new ArrayList[n];`**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = in.nextInt();
//Declare your two dimensional ArrayList of Strings.
ArrayList[] set = new ArrayList[size];

//Populate it. 
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    int innerSize = in.nextInt();
    set[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int j=0;j<innerSize;j++){  
        set[i].add(in.nextLine());                
    }
}        
try{
    System.out.println(set[0].get(1));
    System.out.println(set[1].get(2));
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("ERROR!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
public class JavaTests {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[ ][ ] test2 = new String[3][3];      //3 can be replace if you add more test2[?][?] = "RandomString"

        test2[0][0] = "String1";
        test2[0][1] = "String2";
        test2[0][2] = "String3";

        test2[1][0] = "String4";
        test2[1][1] = "String5";
        test2[1][2] = "String6";

        test2[2][0] = "String7";
        test2[2][1] = "String8";
        test2[2][2] = "String9";

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
                System.out.print(test2[i][j] +"\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }  
        System.out.println("\n");      
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not just a normal array?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2D array like Below -

**for primitive data types -**

```
int[][] arr = new int[10][10];
```

***for Custom Classes -***

```
public class MyClass {
    int x;
    MyClass() { 
        this.x = 0
    }
}

MyClass[][] arr = new MyClass[10][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        arr[i][j] = new MyClass();
    }
}
```