# How to create an 2D ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2D array that each cell is an `ArrayList`!

I consider this defintions, but I can not add anything to them
are these defintions true?!

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

or

```
ArrayList[][] table = new ArrayList[10][10];

//table.add??????
```

Please help me

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768170/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-string-arraylist

Comment: Hi. The title of the question is not consistent with its content. Do you want a 2D array of ArrayList (something like 3D, finally) or a 2D ArrayList (an ArrayList of ArrayList)? If you ask this for your homework, could you write the original question.
Finally, do you absolutely need to declare ArrayList. Can you use list intead?

Comment: Oh and you declare  2D ArrayList of String in the first part of your question. Is that correct that you need to put String in your inner ArrayList?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

*I want to create a 2D array that each cell is an ArrayList!*

If you want to create a 2D **array** of `ArrayList`.Then you can do this :

```
ArrayList[][] table = new ArrayList[10][10];
table[0][0] = new ArrayList(); // add another ArrayList object to [0,0]
table[0][0].add(); // add object to that ArrayList
```

Comment: Compiler error only if `arrayListObject` is not an `ArrayList` object.

Comment: table [0][0] is null so fistly you need to initialize it.

Comment: Aside from the null side of things, this is the nicest solution we've seen on here. +1

Comment: Thanks, overlooked it.

Comment: Actually, I am getting a warning `unchecked call to add(e) as a member of the raw type` that the datatype is not specified for the inner arraylist, how to do that ?

Answer (score 52):

The best way is to use a `List` within a `List`:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 36):

1st of all, when you declare a variable in java, you should declare it using Interfaces even if you specify the implementation when instantiating it

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

should be written

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>(size);
```

Then you will have to instantiate all columns of your 2d array

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)  {
        listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
```

And you will use it like this :

```
listOfLists.get(0).add("foobar");
```

But if you really want to **"create a 2D array that each cell is an ArrayList!"**

Then you must go the [dijkstra way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956842/3049655).

Comment: shouldn;t it be for(List<String> col : listOfLists )?

Comment: indeed :) feel free to edit

Comment: This is just false, you can't modify the `listOfLists` structure this way! You are iterating through an empty structure so the `for` will do nothing and the following `get` will then throw an exception.

Comment: indeed :) it needs a good old for

Comment: Hi, I see you specified the size within ( ), which is the size of ArrayList on the outer side. What should I do to specify the size of each inner ArrayList in the outer ArrayList?

Comment: in the initialisation for loop.

Comment: "when you declare a variable in java, you should declare it using Interfaces even if you specify the implementation when instantiating it".. @Gab I'm not sure I understand that. Why would one do that? Doesn't that limit you to calling only those methods on the variable which are contained in the interface? It also forces explicit type casting in case you want the additional methods the implementation class provides. So I'd like to understand why you suggested that

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<String>[][] list = new ArrayList[10][10];
list[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
list[0][0].add("test");
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieve by creating object of List data structure, as follows

List list = new ArrayList();

For more information refer this link

[How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-multidemensional-arraylist-in-java)