# 2D ArrayList, add an ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to create a 2d ArrayList but I'm having some trouble adding one list to another. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956720/how-to-create-an-2d-arraylist-in-java) that seemed to answer my question but when I try it out myself I get a red warning squiggle under the last add on coordinates.add()

Here's my code

```
ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
buffer.add("123");
buffer.add("abc");

coordinates.add(buffer);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're using at least Java 7, be sure to use the [diamond operator `<>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/5743988)

Answer (score 2):

you created two arraylist of string name coordinates and buffer. so you can not add one arraylist into a arraylist of string . if you want to add a array list into another then try following code

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> coordinates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
  buffer.add("123");
  buffer.add("abc");

  coordinates.add(buffer);
```

Comment: Im tired and its late, I had it set to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>and I must of changed it and forgot to put it back.. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

`coordinates` should be of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> coordinates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

- like this : coordinates.addAll(buffer);

Comment: Please add description and more detail to the answer just for helps more

Answer (score 0):

Just use **addAll** method Instead of using add like below:

```
ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
buffer.add("123");
buffer.add("abc");

coordinates.addAll(buffer);
```

it will not give any error or warning..
thank you..