# How to count raw and colomn for ArrayList Model with Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I ask question, i have model array list but i want Value in model array list convert or add to ArrayList 2 Dimension in java.?

My code:

class Abc:

```
public class Abc {

    private Integer value1;
    private Integer value2;
    private Integer value3;
    private Integer value4;


public Abc(){
}

    public Integer getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(Integer value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public Integer getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(Integer value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public Integer getValue3() {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(Integer value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }

    public Integer getValue4() {
        return value4;
    }

    public void setValue4(Integer value4) {
        this.value4 = value4;
    }
}
```

Class Main:

```
public class Ebd {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        List<Abc> itemAbc = new ArrayList<Abc>();
        Abc model1 = new Abc();
        model1.setValue1(6);
        model1.setValue2(4);
        model1.setValue3(3);
        model1.setValue4(5);
        itemAbc.add(model1);

        model1.setValue1(3);
        model1.setValue2(1);
        model1.setValue3(6);
        model1.setValue4(4);
        itemAbc.add(model1);
    }
}
```

itemAbc => int a [] [] .....??

F = {{6,4,3,5},{3,1,6,4}}

i want matrix:

```
R = 6,4,3,5

    3,1,6,4
```

And you can get R(1,1) = 6.

How send value array list itemAbc to Array 2 dimensi.?

Thanks.

Comment: what is Abc....?

Comment: @YCF_L  Abc is class

Comment: Hi! How do you want to decide which index of the two dimension array to put your list elements?

Comment: it can be easy if you use `private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` instead of 4 attributes in your class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an 2D ArrayList in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956720/how-to-create-an-2d-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: @codeRock so if i create array 2 dimension and i set value to model. How? Any idea.?

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. Following code will convert your list to two dimensional array.

    private  int[][] to2DArray(List<Abc> itemAbc){
        int[][] a  = null;
        if(itemAbc!=null){
            a = new  int[itemAbc.size()][4];
            int i = 0;
            for(Abc abc : itemAbc){
                a[i][0] = abc.getValue1();
                a[i][1] = abc.getValue2();
                a[i][2] = abc.getValue3();
                a[i][3] = abc.getValue4();
                i++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

 2. You are missing initialization of Abc object after adding first object .

            List<Abc> itemAbc = new ArrayList<Abc>();
            Abc model1 = new Abc();
            model1.setValue1(6);
            model1.setValue2(4);
            model1.setValue3(3);
            model1.setValue4(5);
            itemAbc.add(model1);
            model1 =new Abc();// line you are missing.
            model1.setValue1(3);
            model1.setValue2(1);
            model1.setValue3(6);
            model1.setValue4(4);
            itemAbc.add(model1);
```