# Android Studio How to use 2d ArrayList to add ArrayList of Group names connected with an ArrayList of Members?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-studio

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I can't seem to find the specific answer for my problem. I have a layout in android studio in which I can click a button to create a group. When clicked, I want to be able to store group names in the first ArrayList, and have the inner ArrayList filled with a list of members as they are added to the respective group.

So I will have an ArrayList of Group Names, and each of these names will have an ArrayList of members. I declared it as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> gcinfo = new    
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The following was taken from here:

[How do I declare a 2D String arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768170/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-string-arraylist)

```
List<List<String>> ls2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
x.add("Hello");
x.add("world!");
ls2d.add(x);
for(List<String> ls : ls2d) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls.toArray()));
}
```

The code above makes sense and I assume I can change it the above code form List to ArrayList, but how do I set a 'String groupName' in ls2d when a new group is created?

Side Question: Given that I have not been able to figure this out yet, would I be able to use ArrayAdapter with the 2d ArrayList I want to create?

Comment: I don't think you can use an ArrayAdapter with a 2D ArrayList. Instead you can create a customized Adapter by extending BaseAdapter.

Comment: Why not using a HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> ? Wouldn't it be easier?

Answer (score 1):

Create class called group,

```
Class Group{
 private String name;
 private List<String> list;

 // gatter and setter
}
```

Use this class as type for your list.