# How to add inputs of ArrayList <String> to a nested arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a method that takes in a nested ArrayList of Strings as a parameter as given below:

```
 public static String methodName(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> param1,ArrayList<Integer> param2){
...some logic
}
```

I want to test this method with an input

```
input :"param1"= [
    ["HTML", "C#"],
    ["C#", "Python"],
    ["Python", "HTML"]
  ]
  "param2"= [0, 0, 1]
```

I searched online and found this : [How do I declare a 2D String arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768170/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-string-arraylist)

Here is what I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> param1 = ...what should I put here?    

  List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
   List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
   input.add({"HTML", "C#"});//does not compile ... array initializer not allowed here
  input.add({"C#", "Python"});
  input.add({"Python", "HTML"});
```

How would you add the input to the nested ArrayList?
Would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `param1` is declared as `ArrayList<ArrayList<...>>`, you have no choice, but to create `new ArrayList(...)` explicitly for nested elements:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> param1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("HTML", "C#")),
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("C#", "Python"))
));
```

---

But, as the general rule, try to write functions that accept as permissive parameter types as possible. In this case, if you can replace `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in `methodName` with `List<List<String>>`, that would be much better for the users of your function.

For example, they would be able to create `param1` as such:

```java
List<List<String>> param1 = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("HTML", "C#"),
    Arrays.asList("C#", "Python")
);
```

---

**UPD** as @DavidConrad pointed out, you can use `List.of(...)` instead of `Arrays.asList(...)` since Java 9.

Comment: Thanks for this... both solutions worked. I needed the ArrayList option for local testing. Appreciate your insights.

Comment: Or using `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(); // No need for List<String> again, just the one diamond operator is enough here.
list.add(List.of("HTML", "C#"));
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does that mean I can't use ArrayList again as method parameter. is there a way out with ArrayList?

Comment: @kingified You could wrap the `List.of` calls like `new ArrayList<>(List.of("HTML", "C#"))` and use `ArrayList` in the declaration instead of `List`, but programming against the interface rather than the implementation is good advice, and pretty standard in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the insight